# For what reason should i use org.gradle.api.tasks.Exec?

Tags: gradle

I'm pretty new to Gradle and have to invoke a shell command and parse it's console-output.

After doing some research how to achieve this i ended up with two ways:

1. The Gradle-way using the task-`type: Exec` ([`org.gradle.api.tasks.Exec`](http://www.gradle.org/docs/current/dsl/org.gradle.api.tasks.Exec.html)) with `commandLine`.
2. The Groovy/Java-way using [`java.lang.String`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/String.html) with `execute` and [`java.lang.Process`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/Process.html).

The question is, why should i use the Gradle-way over the Java-way or vice versa? I couldn't find any resource pointing out the difference, yet.

Comment: You'll need to define a task for this in any case, and configuring a built-in task type is almost always better than coding an ad-hoc task, for a variety of reasons.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If what You need to do is a pretty standard task it's better to use Gradle's `Exec`. It's just a wrapper that also starts a command under the hood.

If what You're looking for is a better control or untypical command or maybe a dedicated handling of result it better to use `execute()` on `String` (but it's better to pass command as a `List` to avoid parser issues). It's more low level and needs more coding.